# Gmail Notification stopped working on Nexus 4

Tags: notifications, gmail, nexus-4

I have to press the refresh option in Gmail just to get new messages.

I have checked the application and the notification setting is on. I stopped it and then again started it but still it is not working. Is anyone else facing such issue? Android version is 4.2.1

In my accounts it is showing that "Sync is OFF". Has this something to do with this? I always see this option like this and have to go inside it to change Gmail, Currents, Photos, etc. to sync.

Comment: If in your accounts Sync is turned off, that's normal behaviour. Turn Sync on if it should retrieve new messages automatically -- that's what Sync is for.

Comment: Thanks. Actually there was no option coming for setting the Sync on, so i have to remove the account from the device and added it again, now it started working.

Comment: That's strange. Usually one goes to *Settings->Accounts & Sync* and can *switch* Sync off and on again there. Anyhow, as you've solved it (congrats;): Feel free to add your own answer below to show there's a solution for others to find!

Comment: I found this link which solved my similar issue. It walks you step by step on possible solutions. Mine got solved by removing the cached data of the Gmail app and restarting the phone. Note that this will erase your settings such as signature and notifications settings. I couldn't post an answer for some reason so I'm posting as comment ... The link - Problems syncing Gmail on Android - https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2650727?hl=en#ts=2650682,2661639,2661709,2661688,2661691,2661695,2661719 - Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

On stock Android 4.2.2 on my Galaxy Nexus I had the same problem of gmail notifications not working. I checked that in Settings>Data Usage "Auto Sync" was turned on.

Then I went to Settings>Accounts>Google, hit the email address and you see everything that is being synced or not.

Weirdly for me it Gmail sync was inactive after I had recently updated my rom.

This should take care of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue with my phone after downloading a Battery Saver app that I noticed had turned sync off after I had uninstalled the app.

I read through all the comment answers above and no one came close to the Stock ROM 4.2's data sync setup. In the (current at time of post) latest Version of Android the `"Accounts & Sync"` has been removed and all accounts are inline in the Settings `ListView`.

Individual Accounts will only let you `sync now`, there is no option to `"Turn Sync on"` or `"Auto Sync"`

**My setup:**

> Verizon Galaxy Nexus
>   Android 4.2.2 Stock ROM
>   Build Number: JDQ39

**What I did to resolve:**

Go to *Settings*->*Data Usage*->*Menu*->Click *Auto-sync data*

[image]
[image]